# What's the way to find a function on a unity game and how I call it after I find?

Tags: function-hooking

I'm a newbye, so sorry for the basic questions, before anyone downvote the question.

I'm Learning reverse engineering, I've already learned assembly for mips on the computer science underdegree and I know the basic about computer architeture.

I'm trying to make a macro bot for doing simple tasks on a unity game called pokemon trading card game online. It seens it ways built on unity 2018.4.11.

I know I have to find the functions that call what I want, but don't know how to do it and what to do after this. The tutorials are very confusing on this area.

So being objective, can anyone help me what I have to search and what I have to do with what I found, like, if I'm trying to find the function that calls the button to start a play, how can I call it after I found it?

Thank you very much?

Comment: tried using olly-dbg, but the process dont show on the attach panel

Comment: on cheat engine dissect mono, I only found the unity editor classes

Comment: If the game uses C# as some of unity games (without il2cpp) you can try to use dnSpy